# how to do early flush of <head> tag in spring mvc?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

usually spring send whole jsp after processing data in controller and interceptors. 
It is ok if you don't have many js, css resources. 
But if you do then yahoo suggest to use - http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#flush
usually head part is static and doesn't have dynamic elements.So i don't see any reason to wait for processing whole request.
so my question is how to flush head element or template to output even before Controller?

Answer (score 1):

in servlet: response.flushBuffer();

or in jsp:  out.flush();

I think you should find out how the data stream get through JavaEE container